# Creating a "historial" version of data (clone) with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on a web app where I need two separate versions of the data: an "in progress" version that can be altered at will by users and an "approved" version.

I have seen some resources on creating historical tracking, but in my case, I do not want the data 'tucked away' and unused until someone asks for the history.  Both the "approved" and "in progress" versions will be active (though the approved will be read-only)

The class structure would look something like this (simplified for brevity):

```
public class VideoGame
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Monster> Monsters { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Weapon> Weapons { get; set; }

}

public class Monster
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int xOrigin { get; set; }
    public int yOrigin { get; set; }
    public string SpriteFile { get; set; }
}

public class Weapon
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PowerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

So the scenario is user A creates a VideoGame, names it "Death!", then attaches scary monsters and nuclear weapons.  An admin "approves" it, so in some tables like "VideoGame_Approved", "Monster_Approved", etc, that data exists as is.

Meanwhile, user B comes in and edits user A's game.  User B re-names it "Unicorn Adventures," and attaches rainbow monsters and magic weapons.  Only once this revision is approved should it overwrite "Death!" in the approved section.

User A's "Death" game will be constantly accessed, potentially by separate web services and other database-level manipulations.  It should definitely exist as SQL tables.

The database is code-first and there are no restrictions.  The above "_approved" solution is easy with SQL Triggers, but I'm hoping there is something more elegant available with Entity Framework that I'm unaware of.

Any help or hints towards a solid solution for this would be great.

Edit:  Using @SteveGreen's comment below, I came up with two solutions.  This is untested and is a shorthand recreation:

```
public class VideoGame 
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GameVersion Version {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Monster> Monsters { get; set; }
}

public class GameVersion
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid GameID { get; set; }
    //Metadata (dates, approvers, etc.)
}

public class MVCController
{
    public void Approve()
    {
        var viewModel = new VideoGame(); //This is the viewModel or raw data from some source
        using (ProjectContext context = new ProjectContext())
        {
            //this creates a copy of the video game that isn't attached to the context.
            var newVersion = context
                .VideoGames
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include("Monsters")
                .Where(v => v.ID == viewModel.ID)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            newVersion.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            newVersion.Version = new GameVersion();
            newVersion.Version.GameID = newVersion.ID;
            foreach (var m in newVersion.Monsters) { m.ID = Guid.NewGuid() };
            //repeat for weapons

            context.VideoGames.Add(newVersion);
            context.SaveChanges();

            //later on, we can do an extension method to do
            var game = context.Versions.GetLatestVersion(ourGame.ID);
            //do stuff with game
        }
    }
}
```

And solution two:

```
public class BaseGame
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Monster> Monsters { get; set; }
}

public class UnapprovedVideoGame : BaseGame
{
    //additional properties
}

public class ApprovedVideoGame : BaseGame
{
    //additional properties
}

public class ProjectContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<UnapprovedVideoGame> UnapprovedGames;
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ApprovedVideoGame> ApprovedGames;
}
```

Comment: You could create a repository, override the save function to require a status (approved, revision, etc) and or the username. Then copy the latest monster/weapon records to your approved table only when the approved status is passed by an admin.

Comment: Seems like overkill. Why not just have an attribute or table that tells you approval status? That's a very common pattern. http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/timeNarrative.html

Comment: @SteveGreene I appreciate the suggestion, but I need to create a copy of the original data (as above: a copy of VideoGame/Monster/Weapon) as "Pristine" while many users can manipulate the original without effecting the pristine copy.  Your Martin Fowler link has some good ideas, so I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, we do budget software. Our first copy is "pristine" and unchangeable. It lives in a budget  table with budgetId, revisionId. When user changes their budget we generate a new budgetId and increment the revision Id. Lot's of functionality to roll back, clone, etc. without ever touching the original revisionId = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to simply use two tables, much like your "X_approved" strategy. However, rather than using triggers, simply create a new entity and save it in the matching table. For example:

```
public class GameContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<VideoGame> WorkingVideoGames { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VideoGame> VideoGames { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Monster> WorkingMonsters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Monster> Monsters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Weapon> WorkingWeapons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Weapon> Weapons { get; set; }
}
```

Access to the data will always happen against the "live" DbSets (e.g., Weapons) when you need pristine data, or against the "working" DbSets when you need the in-progress data. You'll then want to use a domain service to handle moving those over. As long as your data updates only occur through a service then you can enforce the read-only nature of the approved data by simply not exposing methods to directly update them.

The example below is a very simple, partial implementation showing how you might do both the working save and approval.

```
public class GameService
{
    IDbContextFactory<GameContext> factory; //injected in constructor
    public async Task SaveNewVideoGame(IVideoGameSaveRequest request) //Defined elsewhere
    {
        var vg = new VideoGame(request);
        var monsters = request.Monsters.Select(m=>new Monster(m)).ToList();
        var weapons = request.Weapons.Select(w=>new Weapon(w)).ToList();
        using (GameContext context = factory.Create())
        {
            context.WorkingVideoGames.Add(vg);
            context.WorkingWeapons.AddRange(weapons);
            context.WorkingMonsters.AddRange(monsters);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
    public async Task ApproveVideoGame(IVideoGameApprovalRequest request) //Defined elsewhere
    {
        using (GameContext context = factory.Create())
        {
            VideoGame vg = await context.WorkingVideoGames.FirstOrDefaultAsync(v=>v.ID == request.VideoGameID);
            // These three uses of a .Clone() method indicate creation of a simple method which will
            // return a new entity of the same type with the same property values -- but only a shallow copy
            List<Monster> monsters = vg.Monsters.ToList().Select(m => m.Clone()).ToList();
            List<Weapon> weapons = vg.Weapons.ToList().Select(w => w.Clone()).ToList();
            vg = vg.Clone();
            vg.Monsters.AddRange(monsters);
            vg.Weapons.AddRange(weapons);
            context.VideoGames.Add(vg);
            context.Weapons.AddRange(weapons);
            context.Monsters.AddRange(monsters);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that the code above is untested, so may not reflect exact API.)

Comment: This is a good thought; unfortunately Entity Framework does not allow you to create multiple DbSets of the same type; ie you can't do DBSet<VideoGame> ApprovedGames; DBSet<VideoGame> PendingGames;

That said, I appreciate how thorough the answer was that you gave.